# how do I refresh/reload collection using same context in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework

I have a stand-alone console app which polls the db periodically for changes.

I want to ensure if anyone makes changes to the Db from the web front-end, the console app gets an updated list of entities.

I've been looking at the .Reload() method but this seems to work only on a single entity. I want my select statement on the repository layer to get a refreshed list, as well as any item changes within the list. Effectively a refresh of the whole context for this particular entity.

How do I achieve this, without creating a new context? The reason for not creating a new context is that  I want to be able to still unit test and inject the repo into the consuming service without creating a concrete implementation inside the service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need long living context? You didn't mentioned any valid reason. You can inject factory instead of context to your service. Factory will hide context creation and your service will be able to create as many contexts as it needs to. Long living context is problematic and should be avoided.

Anyway if you need to refres some data you can change `MergeOption` for the set (or `ObjectQuery`):

```
context.MyEntitySet.MergeOption = MergeOption.OverwriteChanges;
var data = context.MyEntitySet.ToList();
```

Comment: The reason for not re-creating the context, is that the consuming service processes inside a loop as a console app. There is no way to inject the repo. dependencies as well as have them create new instances within each iteration. Do you know a way round this?

Comment: @jaffa, you have to DI a factory to create your repos for you.  The factory calls to your IoC container to get an instance every time.  You *must* keep Entity contexts short lived.

Comment: @jaffa: I don't think there is no way. You can create factory for your repositories and inject the factory. In such case service will ask for new repository instance when it needs it.

Comment: @insta: I've created a Func<> on the service constructor. Then I pass a static function which acts as a factory method. Under normal usage, the injected resolver is used to build the required objects.  When under unit test, the resolver that is injected builds mocked objects. Does this sound a reasonable way of getting round this?